# Downloading images

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How would you fixed the crashing and show the progress bar along with stopping it from downloading all the time rather read from the internal storage if the file exist?
I tried using the debugger but that was to no avail

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ProgressDialog.setProgress(int)' on a null object reference
   at heakeme.williams2.HeaDown$DownloadFilesTask.onProgressUpdate(HeaDown.java:169)
   at heakeme.williams2.HeaDown$DownloadFilesTask.onProgressUpdate(HeaDown.java:78)
```

The error above is also being thrown and i kept looking at the lines but i cant identify why the null exception is being thrown
help please

```
package heakeme.williams2;
//HEAKEME WILLIAMS N01126779
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HeaDown extends Fragment {
    URL url1;
    String[] fileName;
    DownloadFilesTask dw;
    ImageView dwn_image;
    View view;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    int k = 0;
    public static final int Progress_download = 0;
    public HeaDown() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hea_down, container, false);
        TextView tv2name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2name);
        Button btndownload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
        btndownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1);
            }
        });
        dwn_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dl_image);
        try {
            url1 = new URL("https://i.guim.co.uk/img/static/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2015/6/22/1434989662374/c0e02075-3bff-4d45-ae40-8e36793c01fe-2060x1592.jpeg?w=300&q=55&auto=format&usm=12&fit=max&s=7a037eadc12ea3e98b7c637c374ad440");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //dw = new DownloadFilesTask();
        return view;
    }
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask < URL, Integer, Long > {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            getActivity().showDialog(Progress_download);
        }
        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(URL...urls) {
            int count = urls.length;
            fileName = new String[count];
            long totalSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                totalSize += DownloadFile(urls[i], i);
                publishProgress((int)((i / (float) count) * 100));
                // Escape early if cancel() is called
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return totalSize;
        }
        private long DownloadFile(URL url, int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int total = 0;
            try {
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                //httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                //httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();
                int response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream input = httpConn.getInputStream();
                    // download the file
                    // each portion will stored into an index
                    String[] path = url.getPath().split("/");
                    // we are interested only in the last index
                    String imageName = path[path.length - 1];
                    //CHANGED GETFILESDIR TO GETACTIVITY
                    String PATH = getActivity() + "/DownLoad/";
                    File folder = new File(PATH);
                    folder.mkdirs();
                    fileName[i] = folder + "/" + imageName;
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder + "/" + fileName);
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return total;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            getActivity().dismissDialog(Progress_download);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded " + result + " bytes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName[0]);
            dwn_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...values) {
            Log.d("MyAsyncTask", "onProgressUpdate - " + values[0]);
            int i = values.length;
            for (int ii = 0; ii < i; ii++) {
                k = k + values[ii];
            }
            progressdialog.setProgress(k);
        }
        public void downloadImage(View view) {
            //  new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
            dw.execute(url1);
        }
        //@Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case Progress_download:
                    progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    progressdialog.setMessage("Downloading Image...");
                    progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                    progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressdialog.show();
                    return progressdialog;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the crash is because your `onCreateDialog` is never being called to initialize your progress dialog. So when your code reaches this line:

```
progressdialog.setProgress(k);
```

The `progressdialog` object is null and crashes. You also have the `onCreateDialog` in the wrong place, it shouldn't be inside your `DownloadFilesTask`. If anything, it should be in your main Fragment (`HeaDown`) class. Even then, you can only override that method if you extend `DialogFragment` instead of `Fragment`.

I think the best way to solve this is to just manually create your `ProgressDialog` without using the `onCreateDialog` convenience. Create a method like this in your main `HeaDown` class:

```
private void showProgressDialog() {
    progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressdialog.setMessage("Downloading Image...");
    progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressdialog.show();
}
```

Replace `getActivity().showDialog(Progress_download)` with a call to `showProgressDialog()` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Brian it worked but it shows downloading the image then crashes after again

Comment: I'm getting this error                                                              
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: heakeme.williams2.Heakeme22Activity@17e431d/DownLoad/c0e02075-3bff-4d45-ae40-8e36793c01fe-2060x1592.jpeg (No such file or directory)

Comment: Ok well this is another issue entirely. Remove the line in your `onPostExecute` that sets the image and try to debug your code to make sure your file is actually being written to disk (sorry, but you probably need to figure this out yourself). Another thing I should mention is that you should not be running `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` in your `onPostExecute` method because that will block your main thread. Decoding the file should be part of your `doInBackground` task because it interacts with file I/O.

Comment: I found the error its the new FileInpputStream it requires an absolute path in fragments

Answer (score 0):

So I did what you said I kind of got it working but it still throwing a file exception error saying it can't find the specified path.

E/BitmapFactory:Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/heakeme.williams2/files/DownLoad/ns70.jpg (No such file or directory)

heakeme.williams2;
    //HEAKEME WILLIAMS N01126779

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HeaDown extends Fragment {
    URL url1;
    String[] fileName;
    DownloadFilesTask dw;
    ImageView dwn_image;
    View view;
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    int k = 0;
    public static final int Progress_download = 0;

    public HeaDown() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    private Dialog showProgressDialog(int progress) {
        switch (progress) {
            case Progress_download:
                progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                progressdialog.setMessage("Downloading Image...");
                progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressdialog.show();
                default:
                    return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hea_down, container, false);
        TextView tv2name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2name);
        Button btndownload = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_download);
       btndownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dw = new DownloadFilesTask();
                dw.execute(url1);
            }
        });
        dwn_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.dl_image);


        try {
            url1 = new URL("http://www.ninasimone.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/ns70.jpg");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }
    private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showProgressDialog(Progress_download);
            //getActivity().showDialog(Progress_download);
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            int count = urls.length;
            fileName = new String[count];
            long totalSize = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                totalSize += DownloadFile(urls[i], i);
                publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
                // Escape early if cancel() is called
                if (isCancelled()) break;
            }
            return totalSize;
        }

        private long DownloadFile(URL url, int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int total = 0;
            try {


                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                    throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");


                HttpURLConnection httpConn  = (HttpURLConnection) conn;

                //httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                //httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpConn.connect();

                int response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    InputStream input = httpConn.getInputStream();

                    // download the file
                    // each portion will stored into an index
                    String[] path = url.getPath().split("/");
                    // we are interested only in the last index
                    String imageName = path[path.length - 1];
                    String PATH = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/DownLoad/" ;
                    File folder = new File(PATH);
                    folder.mkdirs();
                    fileName[i] = folder + "/" + imageName;
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder+"/"+fileName);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    int count;
                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return total;
        }



        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            getActivity().removeDialog(Progress_download);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Downloaded " + result + " bytes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName[0]);
            dwn_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            Log.d("MyAsyncTask","onProgressUpdate - " + values[0]);
            int i = values.length;

            for (int ii = 0; ii< i;ii++){
                k= k+ values[ii];
            }
progressdialog.setProgress(k);
            //.setText(String.valueOf(k));
        }


    }


}
```